# Use numbers instead of alphabet for DirectionsRenderer api Markers

Tags: google-maps, reactjs, google-maps-markers

I successfully display my direction on the google map with markers but I'm having trouble to change the alphabet inside of markers to numbers.

My method looks like,

```
directionDisplay(direction) {
  this.DirectionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({ preserveViewport: true });
  this.DirectionsRenderer.setMap(this.props.map);
  return this.DirectionsRenderer.setDirections(direction);
}
```

and using it

```
DirectionsService.route({
  origin,
  destination,
  waypoints,
  optimizeWaypoints: true,
  travelMode: this.props.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
}, (result, status) => {
  if (status == this.props.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
    this.directionDisplay(result);
  } else {
    console.error(`error fetching directions ${result}`);
  }
});
```

I tried something like `this.DirectionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({ preserveViewport: true, markerOptions: {label: '1'} });` but '1' just overlays on the alphabets instead of replacing them.

Does anyone know how to figure this out?

Thank you,

Comment: You can't change google's markers, but you can use different ones. See http://googlemaps.googlermania.com/google_maps_api_v3/en/map_example_direction_customicon.html